in Ubuntu 24.04 Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ and notification bug
in Ubuntu 24.04 i can't open my hard disk it show nfts not support error in mounting
and notification show not like popup it cover display width ,i can't read any message

notification bug is given below:


Does this answer your question? Wrong fs type bad option bad superblock Just installed Lubuntu 24.04

Often fast start up has set hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
